# CI CD pipeline for testcafe- Jenkinsfile for testcafe

Tags: jenkins, testing, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline, testcafe

Does anybody have an example of a Jenkinsfile for a testcafe? Please share if you have one.
I have seen the testcafe documentation but it doesnot have any reference to Jenkinsfile. I think it gives an example if a free style project.

Answer (score 2):

See step-by-step instructions in this TestCafe help topic: [Integrate TestCafe with Jenkins](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/continuous-integration/jenkins.html).